# Debugging the solution to a possible Bipartition

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I came across this problem

```
We want to split a group of n people (labeled from 1 to n) 
into two groups of any size. Each person may dislike some other people, 
and they should not go into the same group.

Given the integer n and the array dislikes where dislikes[i] = [ai, bi] 
indicates that the person labeled ai does not like the person labeled bi, 
return true if it is possible to split everyone into two groups in this way.

Example 1:

Input: n = 4, dislikes = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,4]]
Output: true
Explanation: group1 [1,4] and group2 [2,3].

Example 2:

Input: n = 3, dislikes = [[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
Output: false

Example 3:

Input: n = 5, dislikes = [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5],[1,5]]
Output: false
```

Below is my approach to the solution:

1. create two lists, `group1` and `group2` and initialise `group1` with `1`
2. generate all the numbers from `2` to `n` in a variable called `num`
3. check if `num` is enemy with `group1` elements, if yes, then check if `num` is enemy with `group2` elements, if yes as well, return False
4. else put `num` in its respective group and goto step 2 with the next value
5. return True

below is the code implementation

```
class Solution(object):
    def possibleBipartition(self, n, dislikes):
        """
        :type n: int
        :type dislikes: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: bool
        """

        group1 = [1]
        group2 = []
    
        for num in range(2, n+1):

            put_to_group_1 = 1
            for _n in group1:
                if [_n, num] in dislikes or [num, _n] in dislikes:
                    put_to_group_1 = 0
                    break
        
            put_to_group_2 = 1
            for _n in group2:
                if[_n, num] in dislikes or [num, _n] in dislikes:
                    put_to_group_2 = 0
                    break
        
            if put_to_group_1 == 0 and put_to_group_2 == 0:
                return False

            if put_to_group_1 == 1:
                group1.append(num)
            else:
                group2.append(num)

        return True
```

However for the following input I am getting `False`, but the expected output is`True`.

```
50
[[21,47],[4,41],[2,41],[36,42],[32,45],[26,28],[32,44],[5,41],[29,44],[10,46],[1,6],[7,42],[46,49],[17,46],[32,35],[11,48],[37,48],[37,43],[8,41],[16,22],[41,43],[11,27],[22,44],[22,28],[18,37],[5,11],[18,46],[22,48],[1,17],[2,32],[21,37],[7,22],[23,41],[30,39],[6,41],[10,22],[36,41],[22,25],[1,12],[2,11],[45,46],[2,22],[1,38],[47,50],[11,15],[2,37],[1,43],[30,45],[4,32],[28,37],[1,21],[23,37],[5,37],[29,40],[6,42],[3,11],[40,42],[26,49],[41,50],[13,41],[20,47],[15,26],[47,49],[5,30],[4,42],[10,30],[6,29],[20,42],[4,37],[28,42],[1,16],[8,32],[16,29],[31,47],[15,47],[1,5],[7,37],[14,47],[30,48],[1,10],[26,43],[15,46],[42,45],[18,42],[25,42],[38,41],[32,39],[6,30],[29,33],[34,37],[26,38],[3,22],[18,47],[42,48],[22,49],[26,34],[22,36],[29,36],[11,25],[41,44],[6,46],[13,22],[11,16],[10,37],[42,43],[12,32],[1,48],[26,40],[22,50],[17,26],[4,22],[11,14],[26,39],[7,11],[23,26],[1,20],[32,33],[30,33],[1,25],[2,30],[2,46],[26,45],[47,48],[5,29],[3,37],[22,34],[20,22],[9,47],[1,4],[36,46],[30,49],[1,9],[3,26],[25,41],[14,29],[1,35],[23,42],[21,32],[24,46],[3,32],[9,42],[33,37],[7,30],[29,45],[27,30],[1,7],[33,42],[17,47],[12,47],[19,41],[3,42],[24,26],[20,29],[11,23],[22,40],[9,37],[31,32],[23,46],[11,38],[27,29],[17,37],[23,30],[14,42],[28,30],[29,31],[1,8],[1,36],[42,50],[21,41],[11,18],[39,41],[32,34],[6,37],[30,38],[21,46],[16,37],[22,24],[17,32],[23,29],[3,30],[8,30],[41,48],[1,39],[8,47],[30,44],[9,46],[22,45],[7,26],[35,42],[1,27],[17,30],[20,46],[18,29],[3,29],[4,30],[3,46]]
```

Can anyone tell me where I might be going wrong with the implementation?

Comment: Consider a group of 6 friends, where the conflict graph forms a hexagon. Exactly one bipartition is possible, but any approach that iterates over the elements in a predetermined order, or iterates over the edges in a predetermined order, can be made to fail. Suppose the vertices of the hexagon are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 as you go clockwise. Suppose you process vertices 1 and 2 first, and place them in opposite groups. If you next process vertex 4, your algorithm has no information about where to place it, but it should be placed with vertex 2. At best you have a 50/50 chance of guessing correctly.

Comment: @kcsquared has added it as a comment on my answer, but I'll still mention this. As pointed out, this approach isn't entirely correct. The added answer explains where you went wrong with your implementation, which doesn'x fix the logical gap in the algorithm reasoning

Answer (score 0):

Consider a scenario:

1. Let's assume that in the dislikes array, we have `[1,6],[2,6]` among other elements (so `6` hates `1` and `2`).
2. Person `1` doesn't hate anybody else
3. After placing everybody into groups, let's say `2` gets placed in group `2`.
4. While placing `6`, you can't put it in either group, since it conflicts with `1` in group `1` and `2` in group `2`.
5. `6` could have been placed in group `1` if you didn't start with the assumption of placing `1` in group `1` (ideally `1` could have been placed in group `2` without conflict).

Long story short, don't start with person `1` in group `1`. Take the first element in the dislikes array, put either of them in either group, and then continue with the algorithm.

Comment: Should 3. say '2 gets placed in group 2'? Also, I don't think the proposed fix to the algorithm works, but it's not clear enough to tell. The standard solution to this problem is DFS on the spanning forest of the graph.

Comment: @kcsquared agreed, the correctness of this algorithm can't be established. This is just to show where OP went wrong in *their* approach